# ¿Cómo defino un campo como único desde CodeFirst Entity Framework .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, code-first

¿Cómo puedo definir que en  el campo  **Email** no pueden repetirse las direcciones de correo electrónicas?

Mi clase:

```
namespace BusinessWebApi.Models
{
    [Table("UserApi")]
    public class UserApi
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "INT")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 3, TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 4, TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con el `IsUnique` , Quedaria algo asi

```
>         [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "VARCHAR", IsUnique = true)]
>         [StringLength(50)]
>         public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: hola ... dice que falta  una directiva de emsanblado o referencia

Comment: Si apretas ctrl + . te sale que te falta algun Using?

Comment: Kevin Restrepo No

Comment: Seguro que si tienes el nugget de EF Core? Porque puede ser que falte referenciarlo

Answer (score 0):

podes probar lo siguiente:

```
[Table("UserApi")]
[Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true)]
public class UserApi
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "INT")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3, TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4, TypeName = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

}
```

Lo Importante es

```
[Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true)]
```

Lo puede utilizar con la libreria EntityFrameworkCore.
En lo personal no suelo configurar asi mis clases, obviamente es a gusto pero te dejo un post en donde deje un ejemplo de como los hago yo, Saludos.

[Configurar las clases con la ModelBuilder en el Context](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463750/error-modelbuilder-en-entityframeworkcore-para-cosmosdb/520424#520424)