# Error ModelBuilder en EntityFrameworkCore para CosmosDB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nosql, azure-storage

Tengo un error molesto en el el modelBuilder de mi contexto con las siguientes entidades.

```
public class SupplierProfile : Entity
{

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Account))]
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Phone Phone { get; set; }
    public Email Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ranking> Rankings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public GeoLocation Location { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(City))]
    public Guid CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }

}

public class City : Entity
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(State))]
    public Guid StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public GeoLocation Position { get; set; }
   
}
```

Siendo mi modelBuilder el problema

```
public static ModelBuilder AddSupplierProfile(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().ToContainer("SupplierProfiles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().HasIndex(x => x.Nickname).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().HasOne(x => x.Account);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsMany(x => x.HistoryChanges);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsOne(x => x.Phone);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsOne(x => x.Email);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address).HasOne(x => x.City);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsMany(x => x.Rankings); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsMany(x => x.Comments); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().HasNoDiscriminator();
        return modelBuilder;
    }
```

Esto debería de agregar al documento de cosmos una entidad insertada de json con la dirección y el Id de la ciudad a la que está haciendo referencia, evidentemente el problema es la clase Address pero no encuentro el problema, estoy seguro que es la clase address por que tambien me da problema este otro modelBuilder

```
public static ModelBuilder AddSupplierProfile(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().ToContainer("SupplierProfiles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().HasIndex(x => x.Nickname).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().HasOne(x => x.Account);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsMany(x => x.HistoryChanges);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsOne(x => x.Phone);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsOne(x => x.Email);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address).HasOne(x => x.City);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsMany(x => x.Rankings); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().OwnsMany(x => x.Comments); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>().HasNoDiscriminator();
        return modelBuilder;
    }
```

La verdad ya he probado de todo y hasta el momento no logro sacar el error, pido su ayuda ya que son las unicas clases de todo el sistema que me están dando dolor de cabeza, el error que me da es el siguiente

> InvalidOperationException: The type 'Address' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema debe estar en que estas "instanciando" cada vez que llamas a la entidad SupplierProfile. Deberias hacerlo una sola vez, como por ejemplo:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierProfile>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Nickname).HasUnicode();

            entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired(False);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.Rankings) // Si tienes un ICollection empiezas con HasMany y lo seleccionas
                .WithOne(p => p.supplierProfile) //En la clase ranking deberias tener una propiedad de la clase supplierProfile
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClaveForanea); //Aqui seleccionas la clave foranea
        });
```

Otra forma mas prolija que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:
Creas una carpeta llamada typebuilder y configuras cada clase por separado, te doy un ejemplo del mio:

```
 public class PedidosTypeBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PedidosModel>
 {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PedidosModel> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.ID_Pedido);

        builder.Property(p => p.NumeroPedido);

        builder.Property(p => p.EstadoPedido)
            .IsRequired(true)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

        builder.Property(p => p.TotalPago)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18,0)");

        builder.Property(p => p.Fecha)
            .IsRequired(false);

        builder.Property(p => p.Seña)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18,0)");

        builder.HasMany(p => p.OrdenDeTrabajo)
            .WithOne(x=>x.Pedidos)
            .HasForeignKey(d=>d.ID_Pedido);

        builder.HasMany(p => p.DetallePedido)
            .WithOne(x => x.Pedidos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_Pedido);

        builder.HasMany(p => p.Factura)
            .WithOne(x => x.Pedidos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_Pedido);
        
        builder.ToTable("Pedidos");
    }
}
```

Y luego en el metodo OnConfiguring (que recibe ModelBuilder) seria así:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Y listo! Espero haberte sido de ayuda. Saludos